# Color not covering the whole screen

Tags: html, css

Does someone know how to fix 
[this issue?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/65btP.jpg)

There's green around, I'd like to known how to remove/let the other color go over it.

Here is the CSS file, I do have 2 css files, not sure if thats a problem.

```css
*{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

body{
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #c4a1a2;
}

.content-wrapper{
    width: 80%;
    margin: 4% 10% 5% 10%;
}

.content-wrapper img{
    width: 100%;
}

.text-wrapper{
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    margin-top: -40%;
}

.text-wrapper h1{
    text-align: center;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-size: 10vw;
    font-family: 'lobster', cursive;
    
    
  <!-- New CSS post -->
  
 html {
 height: 100%;
}

body { 
 margin: 0px;
 height: 100%;
}

h1 { text-align: center; }

.hoofdtabel { 
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
 border-collapse: collapse;
} /* Vervangt cellspacing="0" */

.kop { 
 width: 100%;
    height: 10%;
 background-color:  #5570aa;
 text-align: center;
 font-size: 72px; 
}
    
.menu { 
 width: 12%;
    height: 70%;
 padding: 5px;                   /* Vervangt cellpadding="5" */
 background-color: #9e6171;
 vertical-align: top; 
}

.inhoud { 
 width: 96%;
    height: 85%;
 padding: 5px;
 text-align: left;
 background-color: #b8c6c4;
 vertical-align: top; 
} 
     
.onder {
 width: 100%;
    height: 5%; 
 padding: 5px;
 background-color: black;
 vertical-align: middle;
 text-align: right;
 color: white;
}

.button {
 padding: 16px 32px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 16px;
    margin: 4px 2px;
    transition-duration: 0.4s;
    cursor: pointer;
 background-color: #e9ece5;
    color: black;
    border: 2px solid #b3c2bf;
    width: 100px;

}

.button:hover {
    background-color: #008CBA;
}

.frame {
 height: 100%;
 width: 100%;
 border: none;
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Text Over Image</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="text_over_image.css">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lobster" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="content-wrapper">
            <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/YE31e.png">
            <div class="text-wrapper">
                <h1>Welkom!</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Sorry if I'm making mistakes, I'm new here and new to programming in general.

Missing Picture: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YE31e.png)

*Second CSS file starts after

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take a tour of the [help centre](http://stackoverflow.com/help) to see [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).  We cannot help you if you do not provide any code (a picture of code does not count as code) - see how to create a [MCVE]

Comment: I know you're new to Stack Overflow, but come on, copying and pasting the code in here is not that much work.

Comment: Ok, sorry, I tried to paste correctly but failed. I will read the guide

Comment: @Maharkus Is the post ok now?

Comment: @Thom Getting there :) Do you have the HTML-markup at hand? This would allow us to reproduce the problem and find the solution! Just place it in the code snippet. Another tip: Right now the CSS is where the HTML belongs. This way the code snippet is not going to work quite right. Click "edit the above snippet" and make sure everything is where it belongs.

Comment: @Maharkus I did it all, now I'll wait for an answer. Thanks for helping !

Comment: Much better! It seems the problem isn't in the code you added, though. Maybe the other CSS file has interfering styling? Or a parent-element you have wrapped around it adds has the green color and some padding? Try to look for the element that has the greenish color in its CSS and add the element/CSS class to your code snippet.

Comment: yes, please post the other css file as well

Comment: @DhavalJardosh Done, hope this helps :)

Comment: I can't see any green border, if you accept my edit and run code snippet, you will see there is nothing like that. May be there is some other issue.

Comment: @DhavalJardosh I removed the red-ish color and let it have the standard green background, thanks for helping though, appreciate it allot

Comment: It's working, right?